# HTTP GET + custom header

Tags: php, http, delphi, http-headers, firemonkey

Can't generate a `GET` request with a custom header.

I have a pretty simple PHP-file on server:

```php
<?php

if (empty($_GET['test']))
    {
        echo('0');
    }
else
    {
        echo('1');
    }
?>
```

I tried `TIdHTTP`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('test', 'text');
  Memo1.Text:= IdHttp1.Get('https://example.com');
end;
```

and `THTTPClient`:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NetHTTPClient1.CustHeaders.Add('test', 'text');
  //NetHTTPClient1.CustomHeaders['test'] := 'text';
  Memo1.Text:= NetHTTPClient1.Get('https://example.com', nil).ContentAsString;
end;
```

but the document only renders as `0` and **/var/log/apache2/error.log** contains:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: test in /var/www/html/index.php on line 3
```

It seems that `CustomHeaders['test']` is empty. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up **headers** with **parameters**:

- [`$_GET` contains all parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) when the HTTP method `GET` was used. This is always the queried address itself: in `http://myserver.net/mysite.php?test=hell&other=world` you'd have the parameters `test` and `other` with their respective values.
- [`$_SERVER` contains all headers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Headers are what is sent along with requests and responses. Cookies are always headers:

  ```
  Connection: keep-alive
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  Set-Cookie: p=a; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
  ```

If you want to send and access parameters, then just add them to the address you request:

```delphi
IdHttp1.Get('https://example.com?test=text');
```

If you want to access HTTP headers then do that instead of expecting parameters:

```php
if (empty($_SERVER['test']))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need something like this: https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=46678.0 :)

Comment: @kazuser and, your point is ..., what exactly? Nothing in that Lazarus discussion changes what AmigoJack's answer says.  Your PHP and Delphi code are mismatched. So fix the mismatch. Your PHP code is looking for the custom value in the wrong place.

Comment: Again: do `print_r( $_SERVER );` instead and see what's in that array. You have to read the PHP docs to which I linked if you don't get why `$_GET` is the wrong place to look at.

Comment: Ok, thanks, changed $_GET to $_POST — not exactly what I need, but it works now.

Comment: @kazuser That makes even less sense.